# XMP Library for Ruby

Tags: ruby, xmp

Can anyone recommend an open source Ruby library for adding XMP metadata to JPEG images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MiniExiftool](http://miniexiftool.rubyforge.org/), which is just a wrapper around the [Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) command-line app, is the only open-source one I know of.

There's a [commercial library called Chilkat](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ruby-xmp.asp), but I do not have experience with it, being that it is commercial.